# starting with Git on Windows, receiving sh.exe" : config: command not found

Tags: windows, git, github

I'm just starting out with Git. I've signed up with Github, installed Git for Windows on a Widnows Server 2008 machine. I'm trying to follow these ( http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/ ) instructions. I can cd to .ssh.

```
~/.ssh and I see these files ( id_rsa and id_rsa.pub )
```

On step 2 when I try to run the command

```
config id_rsa id_rsa.pub known_hosts
```

I get this error back

```
sh.exe": config : command not found
```

I think the Git/bin folder is in my $PATH, when I

```
$ echo $PATH
/c/Users/Administrator/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Program Files (x8
6)/PHP/:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/Syste
m32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tool
s/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/M
icrosoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/10
0/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/10
0/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin
```

that comes back and there are programs in there.

I'm pretty sure I followed the default install, what could I be doing wrong. If I should reinstall is it just a simple matter of uninstall/reinstall with Git?

I've tried google but I don't get anything relevant for that error.
Help me stackoverflow, your my only hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a command that you should execute, it's the output of "ls".